# Redshift doesn't recognize newly loaded data as pre-sorted

Tags: amazon-redshift

I am trying to load very large volumes of data into redshift into a single table that will be too cost prohibitive to Vacuum once loaded. To avoid having to vacuum this table, I am loading data using COPY command, from a large number of pre-sorted CSV files. The files I am loading are pre-sorted based on the sort keys defined in the table.

However after loading the first two files, I find that redshift reports the table as ~50% unsorted. I have verified that the files have the data in the correct sort order. Why would redshift not recognize the new incoming data as already sorted?
Do I have to do anything special to let the copy command know that this new data is already in the correct sort order?

I am using the SVV_TABLE_INFO table to determine the sort percentage (using the unsorted field). The sort key is a composite key of three different fields (plane, x, y).

> **Official Answer by Redshift Support:**
>
> Here is what we say officially:
>   http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/vacuum-load-in-sort-key-order.html
>
> When your table has a sort key defined, the table is divided into 2
>   regions:
>
> - sorted, and
> - unsorted
>
> As long as you load data in sorted key order, even though the data is
>   in the unsorted region, it is still in sort key order, so there is no
>   need for VACUUM to ensure the data is sorted. A VACUUM is still needed
>   to move the data from the unsorted region to the sorted region,
>   however this is less critical as the data in the unsorted region is
>   already sorted.

Comment: If you don't mind, some questions to help figure this out for you... How did you query the proportion of unsorted data? Is the `SORTKEY` for the table set to the column that contains the timestamp for each record? Have you examined the Min and Max values associated with the Zone Maps for each block to determine overlap?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I query the unsorted field of SVV_TABLE_INFO table. The sort key is actually a composite key using 3 fields. I don't know yet about zone maps. Will look that up.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein can you point to a resource on how to query zone maps. They look interesting, but google search isnt showing an obvious way to query them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Storing **sorted data** in Amazon Redshift tables has an impact in several areas:

- How data is displayed when `ORDER BY` is not used
- The speed with which data is sorted when using `ORDER BY` (eg sorting is faster if it is mostly pre-sorted)
- The speed of reading data from disk, based upon Zone Maps

While you might want to choose a `SORTKEY` that improves sort speed (eg [Change order of sortkey to descending](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39108135/change-order-of-sortkey-to-descending)), the primary benefit of a `SORTKEY` is to make queries run faster by minimizing disk access through the use of **Zone Maps**.

I admit there doesn't seem to be a lot of documentation available about how Zone Maps work, so I'll try and explain it here.

Amazon Redshift stores data on disk in 1MB blocks. Each block contains **data relating to one column of one table**, and data from that column can occupy multiple blocks. Blocks can be compressed, so they will typically contain more than 1MB of data.

Each block on disk has an associated **Zone Map** that identifies the minimum and maximum value in that block for the column being stored. This enables Redshift to *skip over* blocks that do not contain relevant data. For example, if the `SORTKEY` is a timestamp and a query has a `WHERE` clause that limits data to a specific day, then Redshift can skip over any blocks where the desired date is not within that block.

Once Redshift locates the blocks with desired data, it will load those blocks into memory and will then perform the query across the loaded data.

Queries will run the fastest in Redshift when it **only has to load the fewest possible blocks from disk**. Therefore, it is best to use a `SORTKEY` that commonly matches `WHERE` clauses, such as timestamps where data is often restricted by date ranges. Sometimes it is worth setting the `SORTKEY` to the same column as the `DISTKEY` even though they are used for different purposes.

Zone maps can be viewed via the [STV_BLOCKLIST](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_STV_BLOCKLIST.html) virtual system table. Each row in this table includes:

- Table ID
- Column ID
- Block Number
- Minimum Value of the field stored in this block
- Maximum Value of the field stored in this block
- Sorted/Unsorted flag

I suspect that the Sorted flag is set after the table is vacuumed. However, tables do not necessarily need to be vacuumed. For example, if data is always appended in timestamp order, then the data is already sorted on disk, allowing Zone Maps to work most efficiently.

You mention that your `SORTKEY` is "a composite key using 3 fields". This might not be the best `SORTKEY` to use. It could be worth running some timing tests against tables with different SORTKEYs to determine whether the composite SORTKEY is better than using a single SORTKEY. The composite key would probably perform best if all 3 fields are often used in `WHERE` clauses.

Comment: The primary benefit I am trying to get from the sortkey is that queries and joins with those three columns (always all three specified) are as fast as possible. So if I understand you correctly, you are saying it probably does not matter that redshift doesn't recognize that my data was loaded in sort order, the zone maps will help me get the benefit of the sorted data automatically as my min/max values will be non overlapping? It is surprising that I am unable to get redshift to recognize it though.

Comment: If by "unable to get redshift to recognize it" you mean the Unsorted %, it is just a count of blocks that have changed/added since the last sort. It is not necessarily a bad thing, but you can prove it with testing. As to getting queries and joins to work fastest, you should be using the `DISTKEY` to improve JOIN times and the `SORTKEY` to improve WHERE clauses (or use the same field for both to further improve JOIN speed). It is quite possible that using a composite SORTKEY is actually slowing down your queries, especially if that column that is not used for anything else.

Comment: accepting your answer as it was confirmed by RS support.